# How do you replace an entire HTML input file element with another one using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

If you right click on a webpage and click "View Source" in your web browser and you see something like:

```
<input type="file" id="filename" name="filename" size="40/>
```

and you want to replace it with a slight modified version like:

```
<input type="file" id="file_0" name="file_0" size="40/><input type=hidden name="randominput" value="somevalue">
```

How would you do this in jQuery?

I tried the following which did not work:

```
$(' <input type="file" id="filename" name="filename" size="40/>').replaceWith('<input type="file" id="file_0" name="file_0" size="40/><input type=hidden name="randominput" value="somevalue">');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need something like that:

```
$("#filename").parent().html("your new html here");
```

You need to get the parent, because else you would insert the new tag inside the old one.

But getting the parent you get rid off the old tag, substituting it with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var newInput = $('<input>');
newInput
   .attr('type','file')
   .attr('id','file_0')
   .attr('name','file_0')
   .attr('size','40');

var hiddenInput = $('<input>');
hiddenInputer.attr('type','hidden')
   .attr('name','randomInput')
   .attr('value','someValue');

newInput.append(hiddenInput);
$('#filename').replaceWith(newInput);
```